# How do you tell someone to vocally act out a part?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Acting or vocally acting a part out?

Let's say someone plays an audio clip and hears:

> "Hurry, hurry up or we're gonna all die!"

How do you tell someone to vocally act out that part? Saying "vocally act out that part" doesn't sound right, but I can't think of a better wording.

Comment: A part involves more than one line. Plays and scripts have many actors playing parts characters with lines to say). Please say that sentence out loud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is "Voice Acting" by "Voice-over Artists" : Details here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_acting

> This is an Audition to select one among the candidates.
> I want you to "voice-act" the character, with suitable emotion and urgency.

In other Contexts, it might also be :

> Here is Mickey Mouse trying to help his gang escape.
> I want your voice to "Mimic" or "Imitate" the character.